# substring from bash variable starting from character position

Tags: bash, variables, position, character, substring

simple question, but my sed command is not working :(

```
echo "some_class" | sed -e 's/.+\_\(.+\)/\1/'
```

I want everything that happens to be after _ character. Please, how can I fix my code to work? Thank you.

In this case, "class" is the right answer.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `sed`; you can use parameter expansion to return the substring beginning with the first `_`:

```
foo=some_class
echo "${foo#*_}"
```

Answer (score 3):

this sed line works for your example:

```
sed 's/.*_//'
```

with your example:

```
kent$  echo "some_class"|sed 's/.*_//'
class
```

Comment: argh. I tried this before: sed -e 's/.+_//' but it is not working with + instead of *. Thanks for your solution.

Comment: @Perlnika with BRE, you need to escape the `+` to give it special meaning.